# discord.js reaction collector function returning error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

hey ive made this function that should be putting a reactions onto a message it sent (msg is handled through the command itself) it reacts to the message but never collects anything and after some tweaking it now produces an error i have no idea how to fix at my skill level any help would be amazing.

```js
function reactionReactMessage(emoticons, msg){
    for(i in emoticons){
        msg.react(emoticons[i])
        return true;
    }
}

function reactionCollect(emoticons, msg){
    
      if(reactionReactMessage(emoticons, msg)){

       msg.awaitReactions({ time: 60000, max: 1}).then(collected => {
            let ret = collected.first().emoji.name
             console.log(ret)
            return ret;
    })
    }
}

//Error
(node:22724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is a object and not a function
```

error provided above it wont point me to where it is stuffing :/